# Customize bash prompt PS1

Tags: bash, prompt

I customize my bash prompt with:

```
PS1='\e[0;36m\u.\h
\e[0;31m $ux \e[0;92m \e[0;36m \@* \e[0;31m\w\n\e[0;92m\$ '
```

the output works and looks fine

but when i use a the arrowkeys to scroll in the history

after 5-10 hits of scrolling i cant move to the beginning of the line to modify the

code/command i found and

i see a part of the last command

command i execute:

**$ ps aux | grep ssh**

after scrolling i see

as an example in the prompt line

**$ ps aux**
and i can only start write after the **aux**

so i push ctrl+c for new line / cancel command

Did I forget a character after the **$**?

This is my Prompt:

```
z4o.ubuntu
   12:46 * /
$
```

when i copy/paste long commands i have the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put invisible sequences inside `\[ \]` (or in `\x01 \x02` bytes). Consult Bash manual.

```
PS1='\[\e[0;36m\]printable stuff\[\e[sequence\]'
```

Bash does not know how many columns the displayed characters take. `\e[0;36m` prints 7 characters, but does not move the cursor. You have to communicate that to Bash.